# Adding help button for each window

Tags: cocoa

I have found that user can associate help with his application using Help Viewer. Users typically launch Help Viewer by choosing the application help item from the Help menu, or by typing a query in the Spotlight For Help text field in the Help menu.

I have some different requirement: I want to associate component specific help to my application, means that there will be a small '?' marked icon at bottom left corner of a window and when user clicks it, appropriate help page will open. This case is similar to 'print' panels where there is a small '?' icon.

Can anyone suggest me some way to accomplish it, if it is possible?

Thanks,

Miraaj

Answer (score 1):

The following thread may be of help: http://lists.apple.com/archives/apple-help-authoring/2001/Sep/msg00000.html.